# Websocket connection from ESP32 to Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, esp32

I am sending the I2S data from ESP32 server to Winform client. Even the client is connected the Serial monitor doesn't show it is connected. Also no data is transmitted from the server to client.
But once the Winform is closed, the serial monitor displays "Client Disconnected". What could be reason here ?

Server side code

```
#include <driver/i2s.h>
#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>

const i2s_port_t I2S_PORT = I2S_NUM_0;
//-----------------------------------------------
const char* ssid = "xxx";
const char* password = "xxx";

//WiFiServer server (80);
using namespace websockets;
WebsocketsServer server;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Configuring I2S...");
  esp_err_t err;

  // The I2S configuration 
 
  // The pin config as per the setup
  
 // Configuring the I2S driver and pins.
    }
  Serial.println("I2S driver installed.");

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print("."); delay(500);  
  }
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.print("WiFi connected with IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  server.listen(81);
}

void loop() {
  WebsocketsClient client = server.accept();
  
  
   if(client.available())
   {
    WebsocketsMessage msg = client.readBlocking();
    
    Serial.println("Client Connected");
    Serial.println(msg.data());

    int32_t sample = 0;
  int bytes_read = i2s_pop_sample(I2S_PORT, (char *)&sample, portMAX_DELAY); // no timeout
  if (bytes_read > 0) {
    String sampleString = String(sample);
    client.send(sampleString);
    Serial.println(sampleString);
  }
}
    Serial.println("Client Disconnected");
   }
```

Client side code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;

        }

        private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            textstatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                textstatus.Text += e.MessageString;
               
            });
        }

        SimpleTcpClient client;

        private void btnconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.Connect(texthost.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textport.Text));
            btnconnect.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //client.WriteLineAndGetReply(textmessage.Text,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            client.WriteLine(textmessage.Text);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be using websockets on one side, and simple TCP sockets on the other. These aren't really the same thing. Make sure your two applications agree on what transmission method, protocol and data format they are using to communicate with each other.

Comment: Can't tell because I do not have the code for i2s_pop_sample()

Comment: ```int32_t sample = 0;
  int bytes_read = i2s_pop_sample(I2S_PORT, (char *)&sample, portMAX_DELAY);``` @jdweng

Comment: @ADyson’s comment is correct. Winsocket is a different protocol from a raw TCP connection. Your code fails for that reason.

Comment: The method is depricated.  See : https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.3/api-reference/peripherals/i2s.html.  It been 35 years since I worked on a I2C project.  We often had hangups when using the interface and I was the one who usually fixed the issues.   There is a master and slaves on the bus and unless then modes are properly the interface will not work.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C

Comment: Instead of connecting the c#, when connected to the browser it gives reading and also in serial plotter as well. @jdweng

Comment: Every device is different.  You have to read the documentation carefully or capture working application and reverse engineer the working code.  I solved lots of these type issues with my own projects and know that I cannot solve the problem remotely.